# how to print path of a file pointed by a symbolic link in C like tree or ls -l does

Tags: c, linux, tree, symlink, ls

here's my problem:
Im writing a simplified tree command with C language.
When I find a file that's a symbolic link i would print something like:

SymbolicFile -> ../.././something..

So i've tried to do that using readlink() function, but it does not print the file pointed to the symbolic link as the ls -l or tree command does.

for example:
if my symbolic link file is there 0/1/2/3/symbolic and the file pointed is in 0/1/a/b/filepointed.

My program prints: symbolic -> 0/1/a/b/filepointed
But i want this: symbolic -> ../../.././a/b/filepointed (as ls -l or tree does).

So what would be a way to do that?

Comment: Not sure if there is such function, but you can always call `ls` with any arguments you want. See the `exec` family functions.

Comment: I forgot to say that this program is for a homework for which it's proibited the usage of exec :P

Comment: Use `lstat` (vs. `stat`) to get info about the _link_ name. Then, `readlink` will return what it points to. You may have to loop on `readlink` because you could have multiple link depths (e.g.) `foo` --> `../dira/bar` --> `../dirb/baz`.

Comment: If you are on a `POSIX` system, you can also use [`realpath()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html).

Comment: In other words, assuming you're looping on entries in a directory `curdir` with `readdir`, you will get back `struct dirent`. In that, you have: `d_name`. Do `lstat(ent->d_name)`. Masking against `st->st_mode` can give you the type. (e.g.) `((st->st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFLNK)` then it's a symlink, you can then do: `readlink(ent->d_name)` to find what it's pointing to.

Comment: So you want to convert the path to one that's relative to your current working directory?

Comment: Can you provide the `mkdir` and `ln` commands needed to create a typical directory tree, expected results, and what you're getting (And the code you're using to get that)? (I kind of wonder if you have a dangling symbolic link)